# Composition of holomorphic function and constant functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve a problem, that might seem easy to you, but i am really stuck with it and would be great if somebody could help me or give me a hint how to show that proof.

Given are two holomorphic functions on the whole $\mathbb{C}$: $f$ and $g$ and $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}: f(g(z))=0$. To show is that $f\equiv 0$ or $g$ is constant.

Okay, what i know is that a composition of two holomorphic functions is also holomorphic. I know also what the theorem of Liouville says: every bounded entire function is constant. $g$ is entire, this is clear, but how to show that it's bounded? Or do i have to show that $\mid g\mid $ could have a local minimum at some point $z_{0}$, so it's $g(z_{0})=0$ or constant?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is not constant. Then there are $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $g(a) \ne g(b)$. Consider $g(\mathbb{C})$. As $\mathbb{C}$ is connected, $g(\mathbb{C})$ is also connected, and since it contains two different points $g(a) \ne g(b)$, it necessarily has an accumulation point (otherwise it would be discrete, and thus disconnected). Since $f(z) = 0$ for $z \in g(\mathbb{C})$, $f$ takes the same values as zero function on a set with an accumulation point $g(\mathbb{C})$. Thus, by the identity theorem for holomorphic functions, $f$ must be zero function.

If you know the open mapping theorem for holomorphic function, you can say conclude that $g(\mathbb{C})$ is actually open, and so $f$ is equal to zero function on an open set, so it's zero everywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I just want to ask what follows from $g(\mathbb{C})$ has an accumulation point? The sequence $z_{n}$ converges to $z$? This step is not very clear for me, the rest i understood. Thank you again.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

Comment: Oki, i got it now! THank you very much!

Comment: @xyzzyz did you use the fact that " A connected metric space with atleast two distinct point is uncountable" to show $g(\mathbb{C})$ is uncountable and hence it has limit point.

Comment: No, I used the fact that a discrete space on more than one point is disconnected. Since $g(\mathbb{C})$ is connected and has more than one point, it has an accumulation point, because a space without an accumulation point is discrete, and thus disconnected if it has more than one point.

Comment: Actually, any point of a connected space is a limit point, at least when space is T1. As metric space are obviously T1, each point of $g(\mathbb{C})$ is a limit point.